# SciChart on apple M1

Tags: reactjs, charts, apple-m1, scichart

I use scichart in my React Native (0.64.4) application.
On android/ios - simulators (mac/windows intel) my app is doing well, but sometimes It crashes on iOS - simulator (Apple M1 Silicon) without any errors in console.
Is anybody have the same issue?
How to figure it out?

Comment: Hi Alex, are you using SciChart.js inside ReactJS in an iOS app? Or are you using SciChart's native iOS charts.

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson Hi. It's react native app

Comment: Yes but the scichart library. Is it scichart for iOS or SciChart for JavaScript.

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson Oh, I didn't catch for the first time. I'm using native charts.

Comment: I have React Native wrapper on two natives scichart librarys for IOS & Android. And I have the similar situation, on android it works fine with out any errors, but on IOS scichart every time crashs with memory leak issue

Comment: Hi Alex, create a small GitHub repo of wrapping SciChart.iOS in React Native and post it on the forums at scichart.com/questions. This will really help as the scichart team are not experts in React Native. We'd love to get this working though!